# Geoserver+Openlayers: How to peform a Thematic Map on a WPS Filtered Geometry

Tags: openlayers, gis, geoserver, wms, wps

I am currently developing a small Openlayers project using Geoserver.

I have been using a WMS base layer and the WPS service to do most calculations like buffer, interseccion, etc. It is very easy to perform and chain these operations.

I can't seem to find, however, a way to perform a thematic map over a geometry object.
The only way I see possible is to attach a SLD file to a WMS request but that just ruins the point of using WPS to chain actions, I think it would actually completely replace WPS.

Is WMS the way to go?

Comment: Why would it ruin the WPS? SLD is just styling of WFS stuff, such as colors, labels etc. but WPS is for calculating buffers and intersections as you said. I think SLD is your way to go!

Comment: I think I may have explained myself terribly wrong.

Comment: I think I may have explained myself terribly. 
Say I have a super cool layer with geometries that represent states of the USA. I use a WPS to filter some states. How do i perform a thematic map over that?

Comment: You can still use a SLD to style the filtered states. Sry I don't know any other method right now. Try to post your question on http://gis.stackexchange.com/ you'll find more experts there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [gis](http://gis.stackexchange.com)